# nextjs で静的なページの sitemap.xml を作成したい

Tags: next.js

nextjs で静的なサイト(via SSG)を作成しているときに、その sitemap.xml をビルド時に生成したくなりました。これを実現する方法/ライブラリなどはありますか?

少し調べてみたところ、例えば https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-sitemap-generator はサーバー利用が前提らしく、静的サイトでの利用には適さないと考えています。

Comment: 試したわけではないので知りませんが、提示されているパッケージでは「Usage for static HTML apps」の節で静的HMLにエクスポートする場合について触れられているようですが、如何ですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ryotarch.com/javascript/react/nextjs-next-sitemap/

こちらの記事を参考に、以下の手順で実行できました。

1. `yarn add next-sitemap`
2. 以下の内容で `next-sitemap.js` を作成

```
module.exports = {
  siteUrl: 'https://my.site.com',
  generateRobotsTxt: true, // (optional)
  outDir: './out' // export のディレクトリ
}
```

3. `next export` の後に `next-sitemap` を実行